# How to get JavaDoc for Eclipse plug-in development?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I just started with developing plug-ins for Eclipse but whenever I create one of the sample projects there is no JavaDoc for the methods that are used in the generated code.

I'm using the HelloWorld example and in there there's for example this generated code:

```java
public void run(IAction action) {
  MessageDialog.openInformation(
    window.getShell(),
    "Miau",
    "Hello, Eclipse world");
}
```

However the `openInformation()` method does not have any JavaDoc attached neither does `MeesageDialog` or any other class/method/interface used in the generated example.

Is there a way to add JavaDoc to those methods/classes/etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether JavaDoc is available depends how you set up your [target platform](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Ftarget.htm). **Source bundles** or **source features** are necessary in order for the IDE to provide JavaDoc.

Moreover, sources allow to debug step through the platform code, look into the source if the documentaion isn't clear enough, etc. Hence, you will probably always want to have the sources.

If you add components to your target platform from a software site, make sure that the *Include source if available* option is checked.

When selecting components, prefer *SDK* features or also include *Resource* features. For example, include the *Eclipse Platform SDK* instead of the *Eclipse Platform* as it also contains source code and documentation. If your target requires the *Eclipse Java Development Tools*, make sure to also include the *Eclipse JDT Plug-in Developer Resources*, again the latter contains documentation and source code.

[image: Add Content Dialog]

Comment: Hm...I have the complete JDT (with resources) and the complete Eclipse SDK installed but I still don't have JavaDoc for the classes generated by the plugin-wizard...In my "normal" java code I have JavaDoc available...Might that be because I'm still using Eclipse 4.4?

Comment: No, nothing to do with Eclipse 4.4. What do you mean by _installed_?

Comment: Eclipse tells me that these things are downloaded and installed when I try to go with Help>Install New Software and then selecting these entities

Comment: Just found out that when I try to open the attached JavaDoc in the Browser it tells me that I have to be configured because it's not configured yet...Do I have to associate the downloaded sources somewhere?

Comment: _Help > Install New Software_ is the wrong way. Read the answer again: components must be contained in a **target platform** if you want to develop against them.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the location was configured to the java site by default for working when online. If you want to have the documentation offline, do this:

First download and extract the javadocs for the JRE version you have installed.

From Eclipse go Windows -> Preferences -> Expand Java -> Installed JREs -> Select the JRE you want docs for -> Click Edit -> Select all of the System Libraries -> Click JavaDoc location and select the location where you extracted the docs.

*EDIT - Just noticed the method you are looking at isn't in core java. If you want to add Java Docs or Source to a referenced library, expand the references then right-click on the jar you want and select preferences, from there you can add the docs or source, which you should be able to download.

Comment: My problem is not that I don't have any JavaDoc at all...For normal java usage it works just fine...Only when I start doing something with plugins and the respective classes I get the note, that there is no JavaDoc attached to that class...